# Deleting Duplicate Rows in a MySQL

Tags: mysql

**My Code:** 
DELETE FROM doctorreport
WHERE id IN (
SELECT id 
FROM doctorreport 
GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) LIMIT 1

**Error:** #1093 - You can't specify target table 'doctorreport' for update in FROM clause

Comment: how do i solve error

Comment: By following the threads linked in your question